# I'm getting irregular output for this program? Why?

Tags: java, methods, try-catch-finally, finally

Finally example

```
public class FinallyExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FinallyExample().dothework();
    }
    public void dothework()
        {
            Object o=null;
            for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(" "+i);
        try{ o=makeObj(i);}catch(IllegalArgumentException e){System.err.println("Error: ("+e.getMessage()+").");}
            finally{System.err.println("All done");
            /*if(o==null)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }*/
            }
            System.out.println(o);
        }
        }
    public Object makeObj(int type) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if(type==1) throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Don't like type"+type);
        return null;
        }
}
```

**The sequence of output is always different!**

I'm using eclipse.

O/P- 
All done
Error: (Don't like type1). 0  //this line should be print when i=1 
null
 1

All done
null
 2
All done
null
 3
All done
null
 4
All done
null

O/P- 0
All donenull
 1

Error: (Don't like type1).
All done
null
 2
All done
null
 3
All done
null
 4
All done
null

Comment: There is only one thread working in program!

Comment: Please format your code consistently when posting on Stack Overflow. It's all over the place at the moment. Also show examples of the output.

Comment: The problem is probably related to the way in which std-out and std-err are cached/flushed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you're writing to `System.out` and `System.err`. It's unclear (and implementation-specific) exactly how much data those will buffer, or when they will be flushed, but you shouldn't necessarily expect that to be consistent every time.

I expected that calling `System.out.flush()` after writing to `System.out`, and `System.err.flush()` after writing to `System.err` would fix this - but in Eclipse at least, it doesn't seem to. (Running the same code in a Windows command prompt gives the same output every time even without the flush.)

Basically, this appears to be an artefact of the Eclipse console implementation. I wouldn't worry about it - just be aware of it when you're trying to diagnose things. (If you send all diagnostic output to the same stream, it won't be a problem.)

Comment: After if(type==1) condition becomes true
o/p 1<br>
Error: (Don't like type1).<br>
All done<br>

sometimes I get 
o/p 1<br>
Error: (Don't like type1).All done
  



why?

Comment: @KushalMaharana: So is your question *really* only about why "All done" is printed before "Error: (don't like type1)" and nothing to do with the rest of the output? It's really unclear *exactly* what you're asking about.

Comment: Thank You so much Jon Steek!